# Android Compose - Image clip and resize parent

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to clip an image (GlideImage which has the contentScale set to crop and its modifier has set and aspect radio of 6:9 - important details)

The clipping is done using a custom shape (code bellow), but after clipping the Box where the image is placed keeps its height and i'm left with a large white space.

Why I'm doing this? Because I would like to only use only the top part of the image based on a given height. There might be smarter ways to achieve it also - open to ideas.

Much appreciated all the help!

```
class CropShape(
    private val height: Float,
    private val radius: Dp
) : Shape {
    override fun createOutline(size: Size, layoutDirection: LayoutDirection, density: Density): Outline {
        val rect = Rect(Offset.Zero, Size(size.width, height))

        return Outline.Rounded(
            RoundRect(
                rect = rect,
                cornerRadius = CornerRadius(CornerSize(radius).toPx(size, density))
            )
        )
    }
}
```